# Using 'tiling' proof technique to create combinatoric proofs about number relationships.

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, combinatorial-proofs, tiling

The number of ways of tiling a $1\times n$ rectangle with $1\times 1$ and $1\times 2$ tiles is $F_{n+1}$.

> (a) Use a tiling argument to give a combinatorial proof that $$F_n^2+F_{n+1}^2=F_{2n+1}\;.$$
>   (b) Use a tiling argument to give a combinatorial proof that $$F_1+F_2+F_3+\ldots+F_n=F_{n+2}-1\;.$$

Comment: Welcome to math SE. What have you tried so far? Please edit your post to include some of your thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

**Hints:**

1. For the first one, what happens if you have a strip of length $2n.$ Imagine what are the **two** possibilities for the slots at $n$ and $n+1.$ They are either separated or united by a tile.
2. For the second one, what if you split the tilings in how many $2\times 1$ tiles you have at the end? What if you have $1$ what if you have $2$? If i do this, which kind of configuration do i miss? Notice that you have to put a $1\times 1$ after you put all your $2\times 1$ tiles to be sure you are not overcounting.